# How does Amanda Waller control Lobo and Johnny Sorrow?

Tags: dc, suicide-squad

I'm reading "Justice League vs Suicide Squad". In the storyline, there was the original Suicide Squad team, which consisted of Rustam, Lobo, Emerald Empress, Dr Polaris, and Johnny Sorrow.

I'm curious how Waller control Lobo and Johnny Sorrow. Lobo is practically unkillable. Kill him 1000 times, and he will come alive 1000 times too. Sorrow is an intangible being, unless his mask is removed. Not sure how the brain bomb will work for these 2 guys.

Comment: For Lobo, Waller could target the Space Dolphins. He is protective of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good old fashion bribery. After the failure of that team she then comes up with the idea to use the brain bombs. Seen in the recent volume of Suicide Squad #9.

[image]

Comment: Jesus christ what is wrong with her neck. Looks like she needs a neck bomb of her own

Comment: Hmm I didn't notice that bribery part. Time to re-read that.

Comment: @Parrotmaster - It’s worst with Waller, but several of the other people have weird necks in the picture above. Comics are a grab bag of art skill, it seems.